# Написать (под)запрос в БД MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Помогите правильно составить запрос в БД MySQL.
Мне нужно из последних 600 записей вытащить 4 последних.
**SELECT * FROM таблица ORDER BY DESC id LIMIT 600**;
Я понимаю, что это делается через подзапрос, но как его написать, не знаю.

Comment: 4 последних из 600 последних - это 4 последних из всех? Или это элементы 597-600 с конца?

Если первое, то почему бы вместо 600 не написать сразу 4?

Если второе, то можно же в вашем запросе написать `LIMIT 596, 4`

Или имелось ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: @BOPOH и тут я вставляю ещё 400 строк и limit 596,4 перестает работать

Comment: Это, так сказать, облегченная версия кода. Сколько записей в БД, неизвестно. Ни первое, ни второе. Хотелось узнать, как всё это в одном запросе получить. Сначала выбрать 600 последних записей, а потом из них достать 4 последних. Я понимаю, что второй вариант подходит, но интересует, как это решить с подзапросом.

Comment: @argamidon, если мне надо выбрать 4 записи из 600 последних, то `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 596, 4` их и выберет, независимо от того, сколько в таблице данных.

А вот сколько будет выполняться ваш запрос, если данных будет хотя бы несколько миллионов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще раз - если надо выбрать 4 последние записи из 600, то надо просто сделать `LIMIT 596, 4`, но если вам так уж необходимо именно через подзапрос сделать, тогда вот вам вариант:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_name`

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM `table_name`
    ORDER BY DESC id LIMIT 600
) as t
USING (id)

ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 4
```

В таком случае внутренний select будет работать с индексом, т.е. очень быстро выберет id и по нему опять применит индекс для того, чтобы выбрать записи из исходной таблицы.

[Здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bd6e/2) можете сравнить планы выполнения трех способов. Привел примеры несколько измененных запросов, чтобы мои запросы отображали тот же результат, что и запрос тов. [@argamidon](/users/14145/argamidon). Обратите внимание на количество затронутых строк и тип доступа к таблицам

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: а ну да, зря я подзапрос вообще писал. Третий вариант ничо такой. Простой

Comment: @argamidon, ну подзапрос - условие автора ) Автора, видимо, интересовала работа с подзапросами, а не с лимитами. Лимиты - это просто конкретная задача.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from (select * from table_name as inner_table order by id desc) as b2 limit 4
```

Вообще-то полагаться на ID как на ключ, сообщающий, "кто был последний, а кто первый", - это очень очень плохо. ID не сообщает о том, кто был вставлен раньше, а кто позже. Используйте для этого триггер с таблицей-аудитом, в которую будет заносится реальное время вставки/обновления строки.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что могу сделать так:
select * from (select * from table_name as inner_table order by id desc limit 600) as b2 limit 4

Comment: @Michael74, это очень плохая идея. Сейчас напишу ответ, который будет работать намного быстрее, вот только смысла в нем мало, если для текущей задачи достаточно сделать `LIMIT 596, 4` (что проще и быстрее)

Comment: если таблица неизменяемая, то пиши 596,4. А если изменяемая, то ты сам понимаешь, какие могут быть последствия 596,4?

Comment: Я понимаю, что идея не очень, но пока тренируешься, хочется решить некоторые вопросы, может, они покажутся глупыми, но для этого этот сайт и существует, чтоб задать вопрос. Знал бы ответ не писал. Спасибо Вам за помощь и совет. Интересно посмотреть на ответ.

Comment: Таблица изменяется  596,4 - не подойдет

Comment: я уже ответил. мой запрос выделяет 4 ряда с максимальными ИД.

Comment: @argamidon, если таблица изменяемая что вернет `LIMIT 600`? 600 последних записей, всегда. Что вернет `LIMIT 596, 4`? 4 записи, начиная с 596, всегда.

И где здесь будет ошибка? Вы что-то не то говорите. Не забывайте - сортировка идет `DESC`, т.е. `LIMIT 600` выбирает записи с конца, а не с начала.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @argamidon,

>> полагаться на ID как на ключ сообщающий "кто был последний, а кто первый" - это очень очень плохо

А вы слышали про автоинкремент? Запись добавляется - счетчик увеличивается. Вы предлагаете ручками сделать то, с чем прекрасно справляется СУБД